# How to link the correct python version when embedding in C++?

Tags: python, c++, macos, python-3.7, python-embedding

I embedded a python interpreter in C++ code. It works fine for the high-level way with:

```
PyRun_SimpleFileEx(fd, "/file_path/some_script.py", 1)
```

But I need to pass some arguments to the python code so I tried to go forward with some code from the python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/extending/embedding.html#compiling-and-linking-under-unix-like-systems) about embedding. However, XCode complains about some functions that are not defined. My guess is that my

```
#include <Python/Python.h>
```

Does not add the right python version and is pointing possibly to the system version (2.7) which doesn't have the headers with the right functions.

My linker Flags are:

```
-lpython3.7m -ldl -framework CoreFoundation
```

I added the Python include folder from the framework to the header search paths:

```
../../Support/Lib/Python/include
```

and the Python Lib folder from the framework to the library search paths:

```
../../Support/Lib/Python/lib
```

The support folder is like indicated to folders up from the solution.

The functions that XCode cannot find are `PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault()` and `Py_FinalizeEx()`.

The first one is defined in `unicodeobject.h` that gets included by `Python.h` its right where it has to be in the include folder as I described above.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, so maybe someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use Python 2.7 headers, period. You have to have Python 3.7 headers coming first in the list of your include paths, otherwise, you will get random success, or failures.

Comment: Using 2.7 headers worked to solve the errors but the python script i want to execute is python 3. So i need to get the right link for python3. Putting the include on top didn't solve the issue it is still linking python2. Any other ideas?

Comment: So #include <Python/Python.h> definetly includes the default python 2.7 from the system. Any idea how to change this?

Comment: No, it's not just the link, you also need to get the Python 3 headers. They are not compatible one with the other! (my comment remove the can**'t**). You **CANNOT** use Python 2 headers and link against Python 3.

Comment: Yes your right and i did change the links and the header files that were linked to. In the end the problem was that i didn't put the correct include statement so when i took #include <Phython/Python> it allways included the system default Python2. So the problem wasn't really the links. But my link path also didn't go till the last folder that had the header in it. Sorry for the confusion i'm quite new to this topic. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Because "Python/Python.h" is the usual proper pattern. The way Python 3 is installed is incorrect, as it's not standard.

Comment: How should python3 be installed correctly to work with #include <Python/Python.h> ? I just copied the include and lib folders of my pyenv Python Frameworks to my Support Folder and used those.

Comment: Try installing Python 3 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ok like allways devil is in the details...
I figured out i only have to pass the full path directly until the top directory of the header files i need. Subdirectories are not searched. So my header search path is:

```
../../Support/Lib/Python/include/python3.7m
```

and my library search path:

```
../../Support/Lib/Python/lib/python3.7 and then just include
```

To include i finally just did:

```
#include <Python.h>
```